# Scheduled IPtables rules vs docker rules automatically added

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables

I have cron job that periodically refresh my iptables rules from sh script file.
This is aworking solid file with tested rules and a secure way in case I will cut myself off the server to re-enable working setup in a while.

Off course the first command in this file is `iptables -F` to remove all chains and then setup the right rlues.

Now docker add its own rules everytime you run docker command.

It is ok up to a moment when my croned mechanism overwrite those automatic docker rules. Thus every cron execution flush the docker rules.

**How to solve the issue so that the safety mechnizm could stay and the dynamic rules form each docker command could be applied?**

Comment: Solution is to add the following rules to the croned script: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7

Comment: You can answer the question and accept it yourself. Looks like a common enough scenario to me.